# Simulink: select element from a vector in relation with the current time

Tags: matlab, vector, block, simulink, sample

I'm new to Simulink I have a long vector and I want to select one single element for every time (sampled every five seconds).

For example if I have a vector V = [100 2 192 18 5 ...] I want to select at times t=1, t=2, t=3, t=4, t=5 the element V[1] = 100, at time t=6, t=7, 7=8, t=9, t=10 the element V[6] = 2, and so on.

Is there a block or a set of block to do so? And what options should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Define a two column matrix in MATLAB where the first column are the time points and the second column are your data values.  I'd recommend always starting the time vector at t = 0.

```
V = [0 100 2 192 18 5 ...];
t = [0 1 6 11 15 ...]; % better to use [0 1:5:Something], but you haven't said what the final time is
myData = [t(:) V(:)];  % must be 2 columns
```

Then in the model use a [From Workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block.
Make the name of the variable `myData` (or whatever name you use in the MATLAB code), and ensure that you **de-select** the `Interpolate Data` option in the block dialog.